# how to save a lxml etree list to csv in python

Tags: python, json, csv, xpath, lxml

I am trying to store data that I parsed using lxml and xpath to a CSV or JSON file.
I am using python3.6
Here is what I tried

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import html


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get("https://www.capfriendly.com/teams/bruins", headers=headers).text
# Parse the body into a tree
parsed_body = html.fromstring(response)
# Perform xpaths on the tree
parsed_body.xpath('//tr/td//text()')
team_data = open('capData.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(team_data)
count = 0
for tbl in parsed_body.xpath('//table'):
    elements = tbl.xpath('.//tr/td//text()')
    for el in elements:
            if count == 0:
                count += 1
    csvwriter.writerow(elements)
```

I get all the data in one row

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are 3 table, which table is you need

Comment: The one that says cap hit (Fowards, Defense, Goal tenders, and non roasters players)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get help solving this problem please refer to this question [How to avoid getting concatenated data in one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288444/how-do-i-avoid-data-from-different-tabs-to-be-concatenated-in-one-cell-when-i-sc/42289030#42289030)

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('https://www.capfriendly.com/teams/bruins')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find(id="team")
for tr in table('tr', class_=['odd', 'even']):  # get all tr whose class is odd or even
    row = [td.text for td in tr('td')]          # extract td's text
    print(row)
```

out:

```
['Krejci, David "A"', 'NMC', 'C', 'NHL', '30', '$7,250,000$7,250,000NMC', '$7,250,000$7,500,000NMC', '$7,250,000$7,500,000NMC', '$7,250,000$7,000,000Modified NTC', '$7,250,000$7,000,000Modified NTC', 'UFA', '']
['Bergeron, Patrice "A"', 'NMC', 'C', 'NHL', '31', '$6,875,000$8,750,000NMC', '$6,875,000$8,750,000NMC', '$6,875,000$6,875,000$6,000,000NMC', '$6,875,000$4,375,000$3,500,000NMC', '$6,875,000$4,375,000$1,000,000Modified NTC, NMC', '$6,875,000$4,375,000$1,000,000Modified NTC, NMC', 'UFA']
['Backes, David', 'NMC', 'C, RW', 'NHL', '32', '$6,000,000$8,000,000$3,000,000NMC', '$6,000,000$8,000,000$3,000,000NMC', '$6,000,000$6,000,000$3,000,000NMC', '$6,000,000$4,000,000$3,000,000Modified NTC', '$6,000,000$4,000,000$1,000,000Modified NTC', 'UFA', '']
['Marchand, Brad', 'M-NTC', 'LW', 'NHL', '28', '$4,500,000$5,000,000Modified NTC', '$6,125,000$8,000,000$4,000,000NMC', '$6,125,000$8,000,000$3,000,000NMC', '$6,125,000$7,500,000$4,000,000NMC', '$6,125,000$5,000,000$1,000,000NMC', '$6,125,000$6,500,000$4,000,000NMC', '$6,125,000$5,000,000$3,000,000Modified NTC']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great.

Comment: Based on your answer I added the functionality to save to a csv file       `with open("csvfile.csv", "w", newline='') as team_data:
    for tr in table('tr', class_=['odd', 'even']):  # get all tr whose class is odd or even
        row = [td.text for td in tr('td')]         # extract td's text
        writer = csv.writer(team_data)
        writer.writerow(row) `

Comment: I just realised that the data from different tabs comes concatenated in one cell. For instance `'$7,250,000$7,500,000NMC'` Is there a way to fix this?